# Idiom/proverb applicable when a driver forces his car into roundabout without stopping just because he thinks he has signaled ahead of time

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests, proverb-requests

What is the idiom/proverb applicable to this situation?

> When a driver forces his car into roundabout without stopping (as the traffic rule would recommend) just because he thinks he has signaled ahead of time.

The idea is one should stop before entering into a roundabout rather than forcing one's car into it just because one comes signalling from far away. So here the driver is wrong in the first place and over the top he then throw tantrums post event.

A resembling idiom in hindi is

> Ek  toh (First of) chori (caught stealing) upar se (over the top) seena zori (chest-thumping)

Comment: You're talking about arrogance, e.g. an arrogant motorist, and the sense of entitlement.

Comment: Yes you are right and i am seeking an idiom/proverb

Comment: What's wrong with "arrogant motorist"? Are you looking for an idiom/proverb about arrogance in general?

Comment: [*There is always the few who don't wait but try to **bulldoze into the traffic** just because they are driving a huge truck.*](http://asharagam.com/2015/06/07/happenings-for-the-week/) But that's from an Indian source anyway - well-mannered Brits wouldn't dream of doing anything like that.

Comment: Look before you leap.  Partial obedience is disobedience. Passing the buck.

Comment: In Britain at least, you have to _give way_ to vehicles already on the roundabout; you would not need to stop if you could clearly see that there were none (unless there were traffic lights, of course). You signal to indicate which exit you intend to take. To enter a roundabout in front of oncoming traffic would be dangerous driving!

Comment: **Fools rush in where angels fear to tread**. {Fools rush in where angels fear to tread definition. Foolish people are often reckless, attempting feats that the wise avoid. This saying is from “An Essay on Criticism,” by Alexander Pope. }

Comment: @mahmud koya. Declaring the person entitled is more pertinent than fool. of course, fool would be the next best, but it would be apt to say "(Entitled, inconsiderate, thoughtless) rush in where (wiser, astute, sensible, sane) prudent to tread. But i don't know if there is a formal idiom/proverb that fits the bill.

Comment: @KateBunting That is the rule everywhere in the world. Problem people don't abide by few eccentrics. So thats why idiom/proverbs are invented to prove the point. I am looking for one like mahmud koya suggested is very close but misses out the essence like i explained.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth. You can put your response as an answer.

Comment: there is an element of "not taking no as an answer"  if by some chance you wanted some grudging admiration of his pretense.   Sometimes, (all-though it might be dated), you might hear "driving like he owns the road"  .   There may have been a time when "toxic male assertion" had a certain humor to it .

Comment: @AMN, *Haste makes waste*, *Think twice* etc.

Comment: I put it as a 'comment' because I didn't know which one (if any) fitted your requirements. They all relate to the scenario you describe.

Comment: I have another hindi saying that goes on similar lines.  ***** bhi (to rape (the victim) also) aur (and) ghar thk pohocake bhi aneka (to have the audacity to drop the victim at home too). I am sorry if this is indecent to the decorum. I could delete this if it is unfit for an example

Answer (score 2):

**What nerve**! **What (a) nerve**! and **Of all the nerve**! [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/What+nerve!)

> Inf. How rude!